# c# Passing array of objects with global namespace to WebMethod

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I am not being able to generate the request for the following xml:

```
<soapenv:Envelope  
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
xmlns:sga="urn:erp-ws-schemas/codeunit/SGA"  
xmlns:rec="RecogerAlbaranes">    
<soapenv:Header/>    
<soapenv:Body>       
  <sga:RecogerAlbaranes>          
    <sga:parametros>             
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->            
      <Fila>                
        <id>0001</id>  
          ....               
      </Fila>             
      <Fila>                
        <id>0002</id> 
          ....                           
      </Fila>   
       .....                           
    </sga:parametros>       
  </sga:RecogerAlbaranes>    
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The xml request that my webservice has is this one.
The problem is that Fila is using the wrong namespace.

```
<soapenv:Envelope  
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  
xmlns:sga="urn:erp-ws-schemas/codeunit/SGA"  
xmlns:rec="RecogerAlbaranes">    
<soapenv:Header/>    
<soapenv:Body>       
  <sga:RecogerAlbaranes>          
    <sga:parametros>             
      <!--1 or more repetitions:-->            
      <sga:Fila>                
        <id></id>    
        ...                         
      </sga:Fila>   
       ....                                   
    </sga:parametros>       
  </sga:RecogerAlbaranes>    
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My webmethod is like this

```
[WebMethod]  
[SoapDocumentMethod(Action = "RecogerAlbaranes")] 
[return: XmlElementAttribute("response")]  
public XmlDocument RecogerAlbaranes(List<Fila> parametros)  
{ ... }
```

The class Fila:

```
<XmlRoot([Namespace]:="">  
Public Class Fila  
{ ... }
```

I tried to using the attribute xmlns inside Fila class but gives me an error becase its not allowed.

I also tried wrapping Fila array inside a class named cParameters, but that generates a nested `<parametros>`

```
<XmlRoot([Namespace]:="">  
Public Class cParametros   
{ 
   [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Fila", Type = typeof(Fila))]
   [XmlArray(ElementName = "parametros")]
    public List<Fila> parametros { get; set; } = new List<Fila>();
}

public XmlDocument RecogerAlbaranes(cParametros parametros)
{ ... }
```

I have also tried some parameters of `[SoapDocumentMethod]` but without success.

I'm starting to get desperate, is this even possible?

Comment: Hi, you use `[WebMethod]` here? It seems not support asp.net core but asp.net,right? Is your target framework `.NET Framework`?

Comment: Yes my target is .NET Framework. Already changed the tag

Comment: Try : [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Fila", Namesapace = "")]  You do not need the declaration above the Class.  Net library uses the one above the property in the parent class.

Comment: It is a step further, the items have global namespacing, but still generate two nested `<sga:parameters>`, is there a way to directly request the list in the WebMethod without having to use a Parameters class to wrap the list with the attributes?